# A high school problem on derivatives.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came across this problem in an old high school textbook of 1978:

> Suppose that $f, g$ are polynomials with domain and image all of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if
> \begin{equation}
>     \begin{cases} 
>                   f(x)\neq g(x) \\
>                   f''(x)\neq g''(x) 
>     \end{cases} \forall \hspace{.1cm} x\in \mathbb{R}
> \end{equation}
> there is exactly one solution of $f'(x)=g'(x)$
>
>  Clarification: By $f'$ and $f''$, the first and second derivatives are inferred.

I'm not sure what I must do, but I have come up with  a few vague ideas:

- The polynomials can only be of odd order $\geq 3$ and they must have the same coefficient in their largest power. (Otherwise, a new polynomial of odd order would arise, which would oppose the assumption that $f(x)\neq g(x)$)
- I have started by assuming that there is no $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)=g'(x_0),$ which in turn implies that the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is strictly monotone. Can I consider cases? Would that be helpful?
- Also because I need $f''(x)\neq g''(x)$, the function $q(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)$ is also strictly monotone.

There are also other ideas that are just floating around, but I just can't poke the problem well enough. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think that considering the contrapositive would be useful.

Comment: such as: if there are two or more $x$   such that $(f-g)'(x) = 0,$ Rolle's  Theorem says there is a point with $(f-g)''(x) = 0,$

Comment: Other case, if we always have $(f-g)'(x) \neq 0,$  we know $(f-g)'$ is of even degree. But then $(f-g)''$ is of odd degree and has a zero.

Comment: One of the best presented Qs I've seen in a long time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't claim that this is the most elegant solution, but it builds on your own reasoning (I think).

##### There is at least one solution to $f'(x) = g'(x)$.

The intermediate value theorem implies that either
$$ f(x) - g(x) > 0 \qquad\text{or}\qquad f(x) - g(x) < 0 $$
for all $x$.  In either case, $f-g$ is a real polynomial with no roots, which means that $f-g$ is of even degree (as every real polynomial function of odd degree has at least one real root—this is also a consequence of the intermediate value theorem).  The derivative of a polynomial function of even degree is either

1. the zero polynomial, or
2. a polynomial of odd degree.

But if $(f-g)'$ is the zero polynomial, then $f''(x) = g''(x) = 0$ for all $x$.  Therefore $(f-g)'$ is a polynomial of odd degree.  As noted above, every real polynomial of odd degree has a real root, hence $(f-g)'$ has at least one real root.

(A) Therefore there is *at least* one real number $x$ such that $ f'(x) = g'(x)$.

##### There is at most one solution to $f'(x) = g'(x)$.

The intermediate value theorem further implies that either
$$f''(x) - g''(x) > 0 \qquad\text{or}\qquad f''(x) - g''(x) < 0 $$
for all $x$.  This implies that $(f-g)'$ is either strictly increasing, or strictly decreasing (this is a consequence of the mean value theorem).  A strictly monotonic function can have *at most* one root.

(B) Therefore there is *at most* one real number $x$ such that $f'(x) = g'(x)$.

##### From which we conclude...

The two statements (A) and (B) are the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! It seems so obvious now, but I think I felt a bit lightheadedness and confusion. Thanks for clearing it out!